# Apostrophes not being escaped in new server environment

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I've moved a site to a new server and am having trouble determining why the old server properly handles apostrophes in a back end form and the new server does not (breaks sql query).

The site is around 12-13 years old and is very archaic, it does not use prepared statements or `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  For now I'm sending the user input through `mysql_real_escape_string()` as a temporary fix but my real question is why one server handles it differently than the other with identical files and database.

The difference in environments is as follows:

**Old server**

```
mysql: 5.1.72-rel14.10
php: 5.3.29
mysql mode: ""
```

**New server**

```
mysql: 5.5.42-cll
php: 5.4.41
mysql mode: ""
```

The database was `mysqldump`'d from the old server and added to the new server.  I've read through the [Upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) guide and didn't come across anything that could be an issue.

I've tried setting `sql_mode` to include `ANSI` with no results.

What could be causing the difference between environments?

If I've left out any critical information let me know.

**UPDATE:**

Ormoz pointed out that it could be a magic quotes issue, after checking I see that it is indeed enabled on the old server and not the new.  I also see that magic quotes was removed in PHP 5.4 - is there an alternative to globally add a similar feature or would a downgrade to php 5.3 be the only way outside of reworking every SQL query?

Comment: You'll need to amend your question with a bit of sample code regarding how you're actually composing and executing queries.

Comment: You may have trouble with `magic quotes`. In this case use `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off` in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Ormoz great thought, it is indeed enabled on the old server and not the new, I see that it is removed in php 5.4, is there an alternative?

Comment: Since your code is archaic, it's probably easiest to downgrade php. But you should really upgrade your code. Technically there may be some php plugins available but you'd be taking a big risk.